# Inequality involving binomial coefficients

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I recently stumbled upon an inequality involving binomial coefficients. There is reason to suspect that it holds for all $l\in\mathbb{N}$. It states that

$$ (2l+1)^{2l+1} < \sum_{m = 0}^{l} \binom{2l+1}{2m} 2^{2(m-l)}(2l+1)^{2m} $$

I am not sure how to approach this problem (i.e. to prove the inequality) and I am not even sure if the inequality holds for large $l$. Any help on the way to prove this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the summation $\displaystyle \sum_{m = 0}^{l} \binom{2l+1}{2m} 2^{2(m-l)}(2l+1)^{2m}$, at $m=l$ the term is $\displaystyle \binom{2l+1}{2l} 2^{2(l-l)}(2l+1)^{2l} = (2l+1)^{2l+1}$ and the rest of the terms in the summation are positive.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome .. !! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$\sum_{m=0}^{l}\binom{2l+1}{2m}(2l+1)^{2m}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2l-2m}=2\sum_{h\equiv 0\pmod{2}}\binom{2l+1}{h}(2l+1)^h\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2l+1-h}$$
so the RHS equals:
$$ \left(\frac{1}{2}+(2l+1)\right)^{2l+1} + \left(\frac{1}{2}-(2l+1)\right)^{2l+1} $$
or:
$$\left(2l+\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2l+1}-\left(2l+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2l+1} $$
and now it is not difficult to show that such a term is greater than $(2l+1)^{2l+1}$.

Comment: I'd rather use the binomial expansion to prove $\left(2l+\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2l+1}-\left(2l+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2l+1} \ge (2l+1)^{2l+1}$ ;) (+1)

Comment: @r9m: by exploiting convexity we can prove a stronger bound than the one given by the OP, this was the main reason to compute the explicit form of the RHS.

Comment: Ah ! I get your point now ! :-)